# Vaadin Autocomplete component is running in infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin-flow

I am using the Vaadin Autocomplete component from componentfactory.
For dropdown field suggestions.When I use binder inside the addAutocompleteValueAppliedListener function. This function keeps running infinite times. But without a binder, it's working fine.

```
Binder<Product> binder=new Binder<>();

    public void setProduct(Product product)
        {
            this.product = product;
            binder.readBean(product);
        }

    private Component configureForm()
        {
            Autocomplete productName=new Autocomplete();
            IntegerField productId=new IntegerField();
            NumberField price=new NumberField();
             binder.forField(productName).bind(Product::getProductName,Product::setProductName);
            binder.forField(productId).bind(Product::getProductId,Product::setProductId);
            binder.forField(price).bind(Product::getPrice,Product::setPrice);
            
      
           productName.addChangeListener(event->{
                String text = event.getValue();
                productName.setOptions(productService.productNameSuggest(text));
                productName.setLoading(false);
            });
            productName.addAutocompleteValueAppliedListener(event->{
                System.out.println(event.getValue());
                Product fetchedProduct=productService.fetchByName(event.getValue());
           //this line causes infinite loop, without this code running normal                   
           setProduct(fetchedProduct);
                
            });
            productName.addValueClearListener(event->{
                productName.setLoading(true);
                setProduct(null);
            });
        }
```

Help me out,Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you try to do. It seams that the productName field is a kind of a search field. Why is it bound to product?

Comment: Yes, productName is a Vaadin add-on component to show drop-down suggestions while typing. Just like googling. Binder is to bind the POJO's with the field values.

Comment: And that's probably the issue because the Binder changes the value of the field that then still trigger auto complete

Comment: How can i achieve this then, I am trying to create a product management page. If the user types the product name select one from the suggestion. The remaining price,quantity field will get populated automatically from the db. How to achieve this.

Comment: But can the use change the product information?

Comment: Initially, the price and quantity fields will be empty. When a user starts typing the product name suggestions will come. If he selects any value from the suggestion. The product data will be received from the service and the price, quantity field will be populated. This is the idea.